# Creating a scoring system for a quiz using PHP, without using a database

Tags: php, html

I am creating a scoring system for a quiz, without using a database.

If the user correctly answers a question, he receives 10 points. At the end, the total of points is displayed.  I made this function that shows if the user got the question right:

```
function resposta($alternativa, $resposta){
  
    // a $alternativa (name) é oq a pessoa selecionar no radio. A $resposta é informada no value do radio
    // a função exibirá uma msg em verde caso o name corresponda ao value da resposta correta (definir no isset($_POST)
    if($alternativa==$resposta){
        return "<div  style='background-color:green;'>Parabéns, você ganhou 10 pontos!!! <br>  alternativa correta: ".$resposta."</div >";
    }else{
        return "<div style='background-color:red;'>Você marcou a alternativa incorreta e não marcou pontos. <br> alternativa marcada: ".$alternativa."</div> <br> <div  style='background-color:green;'> alternativa correta: ".$resposta."</div >" ;
    }
}
```

I tried to include variable `$p` in the function that would receive `$p+=10` when the user got the answer right.  But I ca not add up the points for all the questions that were answered correctly.

Comment: You could create a function that verifies the answer and returns the number of points to add.  The answer was right, return 10.  The answer was wrong, return 0.  Then you call this verification function for each question, adding the return values from the function into your `$p` variable.  When all questions are verified, you will have your total.  In essence, `$p` resides outside the scope of the function to keep the total.

Answer (score 0):

Without a database; the second-best option would be to use Cookie. Please read some example here, if you haven't : https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Basically; for each user, you get the cookies value 'MY_POINT'. Every-time user got the answer right, you add that cookie 'MY_POINT' by 10, then saves it.
To display current score, do something like
echo 'Your current point is: ' . ($_COOKIE["MY_POINT"]) . '!';

You might want to add a button to reset point. When that button is clicked, do
setcookie("MY_POINT", 0);